# Capybara/Rspec test resulting in post to route that does not exist

Tags: rspec, phantomjs, capybara

My tests with rspec/capybara/phantomJS have been very inconsistent and result in tests that sometimes pass/fail (for stripe in particular) because it will sometimes not enter all the keys that are sent or enter them in the wrong spot (despite identifiers being correct).

That issue aside, when it does enter the data correctly (which is less than 50% of the time), after creating the stripe subscription, the test ends up redirecting to a post to a route to which I have no posts directed to anywhere in my app. Following the same flow through the UI works fine and doesn't post anything here.

To troubleshoot, I've added this post route and stopped the code there to get the referrer controller/method, but this hasn't helped since I have in fact confirmed that there are no posts there (or on any JS file tied to that view). Are there any other ways to figure out what/how is triggering this post request? Is this a capybara bug? Has anybody else ran into any other similar issues?

Comment: Poltegeist/phantomjs is basically equivalent to an 8 year old version of Safari and abandoned - The fact that it has issues with some modern apps is expected at this point.  You're going to be much better off moving to using the selenium driver or one of the new direct CDP drivers like https://github.com/twalpole/apparition

Comment: That was my original plan but I could not get my javascript tests to work with selenium. I was getting a lot of errors and issues when I first started and Phantom was the only one that worked. I'm not sure if it's because I'm on the Windows Linux System (that was my guess). I'll give that one a try. Hopefully it resolves all issues. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I gave that a shot, but I run into issues with the drivers, which is similar with what I got with selenium. I get a can't find chrome driver executable error. I had given the suggestions on this link a try before https://medium.com/@danwhitston/browser-testing-for-ruby-from-within-windows-subsystem-for-linux-fc7dd235a23d but had no luck with the remote server either, so I think I'll just have to stick with the PhantomJS/Poltergeist drivers which while unreliable, at least work sometimes...

Comment: You either have to manually download `chromedriver` and install it in your path, or just add the `webdrivers` gem to your project, require it, and let it do it all for you.  There's a chance that won't work under WSL but it's worth a try - and then specify :selenium_chrome_headless as your driver.